# Múltiplas inserções via foreach em MVC

Tags: mvc, arquitetura-de-software

Tenho uma aplicação que recebe varias observações de uma *view* e preciso inserir isso em uma tabela de observações.

Quero saber se nesse caso, o *controller* é quem faz o `foreach` e então chama o método no modelo para inserir um a um ou se o próprio modelo é quem tem de ser responsável por esse `foreach`.

Qual seria o ideal com MVC? E como pensar sempre ao utilizar um `foreach` em aplicações MVC, isto é, qual camada é responsável pelo quê?

Exemplo:

- Em um cadastro de clientes, posso inserir varias observações;
- O armazenamento dessas observações é feito numa tabela **cliente_obs**;
- O processo para armazenamento hoje é:

  ```
  foreach($input['observacoes'] as $observacao){
      insert cliente_obs($observacao) //exemplo
  }
  ```
- Esse processo se localiza no *controller*

Comment: Ok @Caffé. Atualizando a pergunta.

Comment: O controler é responsável por receber as entradas do usuário e integrá-las ao model. Não há nada que desabone o modo como você fez. Tem algo que você não goste nessa solução?

Comment: Eu gosto dela. Só acordei com 'isso está errado' na mente e queria sanar a dúvida.

Comment: Eu acredito que iss varie de programador para programador. Uns preferem o modelo do *Slim Controller Fat Model* onde o Controller faz pouca coisa (relativamente falando) ao passo que outros preferem o contrário, com uma Model mais magra e objetiva.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto "Fat model"? Não recomendo. Em um bom design, todo mundo tem que ser magrinho! :D

Comment: Pena que o escopo do site seja bastante restrito. Esse seria um bom tópico pra se ter por aqui. Eu não sou exatamente entendido de ORM mas aquilo que eu tenho como mnhas Models tem a apenas propriedades que refletem as colunas do banco. O Table Manager faz o CRUD e o Entity Repositories, desde recentmente, cuidam dos SELECTs específicos.

Comment: Sim sim @BrunoAugusto. Também utilizo repositorios mas todas as minhas relações ficam nos models. Os repositorios assim como os seus cuidavam apenas de persistencia a base. Mas tenho visto que toda regra de negocio que a GUI não tem interferencia, quem precisa ser responsavel por ela é o modelo.

Comment: Exemplo.. Se toda a GUI do seu sistema apresenta a data em d/m/Y, o modelo tem que resolver isso antes de enviar pro controller. Mas se em algum momento a GUI precisar ver apenas a semana daquela data, então a view tem que acionar um helper pra solicitar a semana com base naquela data em d/m/Y.

Comment: Bom eu criei meu "ORM" (e bota aspas nisso) do jeito que eu sei. Não ficou ruim, mas as models não se relacionam automaticamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Seu requisíto de negócio atual

- Em um cadastro de clientes, posso inserir varias observações

Observe que pela descrição do texto, ele diz *posso inserir varias observações*. Como esse processo está envolvido em atualização de estado de um objeto, consequentemente ele estará  envolvido em uma transação. Você deveria fazer o loop de inserts dentro da mesma transação e só no final do processo fazer commit. Assim, caso você tenha algum problema neste meio tempo e queira abortar a ação (você vai querer também apresentar uma mensagem de erro para o usuário [que será originada de uma Exception]), nenhum dos comentários será salvo no banco.

Sendo mais claro, seu loop de inserts não deveria estar em um Controller.

[Veja mais sobre os princípios ACID](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)

**edição extra**: Estou colocando também, uma explicação sobre DDD que vai exatamente de encontro com sua dúvida:

> ... DDD é uma coleção de padrões e princípios que ajudam em seus esforços para construir aplicações que **refletem uma compreensão e a satisfação das exigências do seu negócio** ...

[Veja esta explicação detalhada sobre **DDD**, TDD e BDD](http://www.princiweb.com.br/blog/programacao/tdd/tdd-ddd-e-bdd-praticas-de-desenvolvimento.html).

Comment: Entao o controller nao faz 'nada'? Apenas pega a colecao e manda pro model?

Comment: Muito bom o ACID

Comment: ^ A missão do controller falando em alto nível, é receber o modelo de dados e delegar para um método que faça algo (geralmente o método de negócio quando se fala em sistemas web). No seu caso, seu negócio fala claramente  que espera uma lista de comentários.

Comment: Não acho que sua pergunta é caso de "principalmente baseadas em opiniões", muito pelo contrário, até eu já me peguei com esta dúvida no passado e depois de pesquisar, ficou claro na minha cabeça que não é "questão de opinião". Votei para reabrir :)